# nsisdl Connection timeout error with valid URL (not HTTPS)

Tags: nsis

Using NSIS 3.08 with Windows10, I'm getting a 'timed out on connecting' error with NSISdl for

NSISdl::download "$1" "$6$2"

where $1 is http://download.autodesk.com/us/support/files/autodesk_network_license/nlm11.14.1.3_ipv4_ipv6_win64.msi
$6 is C:\Users\jsmithy\AppData\Local\Temp
and $2 is lmtools_install.msi

the result of nsisdl is "Timed out on connecting"

I have tried adding a timeout but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL redirects to HTTPS and NSISdl does not support that, use [Inetc](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Inetc_plug-in) instead.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that, but how can you tell?